# Choosing file using Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and uploading to server using Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2.6, android-document-provider

> There are some related questions about choosing and uploading files
>   from Android. But those answers are outdated and most of the methods
>   in those responses are gone/deprecated.

I am trying to get a file from the local storage using **Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT** and uploading that to the server using **Retrofit**. But I am unable to convert Uri to File instance. Also, I am not able to upload that file using Retrofit.

Here is the code I have used to get a file:

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val DEVICE_PATH: Int = 398
    private val BASE_URL = "https://pdftoworder.com/"
    private lateinit var pdfClient: PDFClient

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        logging.level = (HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient
                .Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .build()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .build()

        pdfClient = retrofit.create(PDFClient::class.java)


        getPath.setOnClickListener { getFileUri() }
    }


    fun getFileUri(){
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        //intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        intent.type = "*/*"
        intent.type = "application/pdf"
        startActivityForResult(intent, DEVICE_PATH)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == DEVICE_PATH && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            data?.data?.let {uri ->
                Log.d("PATHURL", "${uri.path} ${File(uri.path!!).name}")

                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    //val api_key =  RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "somevalue")
                    try {
                        val api_key = "DzkpCKjktggtCT1ZE8bFqca7anmmkpOcg975".toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                        val tool_uid = "PR5".toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull())


                        val a = getRealPathFromURI(uri)
                        val file: File = File(uri.path!!)

                        val requestFile: RequestBody = file.asRequestBody("application/pdf".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                        val multipartBody: MultipartBody.Part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("input", file.name, requestFile)

                        val result = pdfClient.convert(
                                input = multipartBody,
                                api_key = api_key,
                                tool_uid = tool_uid
                        )




                        Log.d("PATHURL", "${uri.path}")
                    }catch (ex: Exception){
                        Log.d("PATHURL", "fatal ${ex.message}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun getPath(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
        // DocumentProvider
        if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            System.out.println("getPath() uri: " + uri.toString())
            System.out.println("getPath() uri authority: " + uri.getAuthority())
            System.out.println("getPath() uri path: " + uri.getPath())
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if ("com.android.externalstorage.documents" == uri.getAuthority()) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":").toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]
                println("getPath() docId: " + docId + ", split: " + split.size + ", type: " + type)
                // This is for checking Main Memory
                return if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
                    if (split.size > 1) {
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + split[1] + "/"
                    } else {
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/"
                    }
                    // This is for checking SD Card
                } else {
                    "storage" + "/" + docId.replace(":", "/")
                }
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    fun getRealPathFromURI(contentUri: Uri?): String? {
        val proj = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        val cursor = contentResolver.query(contentUri!!, proj, null, null, null) ?: return null
        val column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        return cursor.getString(column_index)
    }
}


interface PDFClient {

    @POST("api/convert")
    @Multipart
    suspend fun convert(
            @Part input: MultipartBody.Part,
            @Part("api_key") api_key: RequestBody,
            @Part("tool_uid") tool_uid: RequestBody
    ): ResponseBody
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/Question_Bank/26_9_day_CSE_summer_final_2018_Wireless Programming.pdf (No such file or directory)
```

Here my goals are:

- Get file from android
- Upload that file to server using retrofit
- Download File from server
- Save that file to the local storage

Any little help would be appreciated. I have also created a [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Zoha131/retrofit_file) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Both `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` give you a `Uri` to some content. There is no requirement that this content be a file on the filesystem, let alone that you can somehow get to that file. Use `InputStreamRequestBody`, as is noted in the duplicate, to upload the content identified by the `Uri` to your server.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you please show me some code? How can I use **InputStreamRequestBody** in Retrofit?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have added **InputStreamRequestBody** and I think It solved the Uri issue. Now I am facing issues with a retrofit. 
```@POST("api/convert")
    @Multipart
    suspend fun convert(
            @Part("input") input: InputStreamRequestBody,
            @Part("api_key") api_key: RequestBody,
            @Part("tool_uid") tool_uid: RequestBody
    ): ResponseBody```
is this legal to use like this?

Comment: I have not needed to do a multipart request in Retrofit in years, sorry.